# how to parameterize a Function Block in CODESYS?

Tags: codesys

I have a FB (SmartLogic) with two boolean input variables and one output variable, but I want the output to depend of a parameter X too which i want to set during instantiation before the FB is called.
Is that possible? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize FBs variables with the FB_Init method.

In CoDeSys help there is information about this methods.

https://help.codesys.com/webapp/_cds_method_fb_init_fb_reinit;product=codesys;version=3.5.16.0

Answer (score 0):

1. If you define `X` as global it will be accessible in your FB.
2. You can pass `X` variable as another input parameter. Simply call FB after you initialize `X` variable.